# Spark sql correlated subquery group by

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Spark SQL version 3.3.

The following query:

```
select d.from_id,
       d.to_id,
       d.hts_code,
       min(d.transaction_date)                                            as earliest_transaction_date,
       max(d.transaction_date)                                            as latest_transaction_date,
       cast(months_between( current_date, max(d.transaction_date)) AS INT) AS months_since_last_transaction,
       (select count(*)
            from quarters q
            WHERE q.from_id = d.from_id
            AND q.to_id = d.to_id
            AND q.hts_code = d.hts_code
            group by q.from_id, q.to_id, q.hts_code
        ) as quarters
from data d
group by d.from_id,
         d.to_id,
         d.hts_code;
```

fails with the following error:

```
AnalysisException: Correlated scalar subquery 'scalarsubquery(d.from_id, d.to_id, d.hts_code)' is neither present in the group by, nor in an aggregate function. Add it to group by using ordinal position or wrap it in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.
```

I cannot add the outer reference in any other place than in WHERE clause in the subquery. I really do not understand what the analyzer is expeciting here.

Answer (score 0):

excusing scala:

```scala
import sparkSession.implicits._
val data = Seq(("a", 1),("b",2),("a", 2)).toDF("letter","number")
data.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
sparkSession.sql(s"""
select letter, number, (
  select count(*)
  from data a
  where o.letter = a.letter
)
from data o
""").show
}
```

yields, as you'd expect:

```
+------+------+----------------------+
|letter|number|scalarsubquery(letter)|
+------+------+----------------------+
|     a|     1|                     2|
|     b|     2|                     1|
|     a|     2|                     2|
+------+------+----------------------+
```

so that's a simple correlated value using count - it can only have one outcome.

Using this query after the above code to simulate a group by:

```scala
sparkSession.sql(s"""
select letter, number, (
  select count(*)
  from data a
  where o.letter = a.letter
  group by a.letter
)
from data o
""").show
```

will cause:

```
A GROUP BY clause in a scalar correlated subquery cannot contain non-correlated columns: letter#7
```

This is similar to the sql you have:

```sql
select count(*)
...
group by q.from_id, q.to_id, q.hts_code
```

that's not valid sql.  You need to have those values in the select (part one of the problem), as you've noted using the outer reference in any place other than having/where gets the error:

```
Expressions referencing the outer query are not supported outside of WHERE/HAVING clauses
```

so next you try:

```scala
sparkSession.sql(s"""
select letter, number, (
  select count(*) c, a.letter
  from data a
  where o.letter = a.letter
  group by a.letter
) thecount
from data o
""").show
```

which leaves the error:

```
Scalar subquery must return only one column, but got 2
```

you can rewrite it as a join:

```scala
sparkSession.sql(s"""
select o.letter, o.number, a.c
from data o join (
  select count(*) c, a.letter
  from data a
  group by a.letter
) a on a.letter = o.letter
""").show
```

yielding:

```
+------+------+---+
|letter|number|  c|
+------+------+---+
|     a|     2|  2|
|     a|     1|  2|
|     b|     2|  1|
+------+------+---+
```

if you must have similar queries as subqueries (for example your fields are defined elsewhere - [Quality](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/) has this approach) you can attempt a rewrite like this:

```scala
sparkSession.sql(s"""
select letter, number,
  (
    select max(c)
    from (
      select count(*) c, letter
      from data
      group by letter
    ) a where o.letter = a.letter
  ) thecount
from data o
""").show
```

which also yields:

```
+------+------+--------+
|letter|number|thecount|
+------+------+--------+
|     a|     1|       2|
|     b|     2|       1|
|     a|     2|       2|
+------+------+--------+
```

You must still have an aggregate return in this case (max, first etc.).

Note as of 3.4/3.5 correlated subqueries can be more powerful - you can use exists and in freely as well [SPARK-36114](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-36114).